# How can I automatically check if a file has changed?

Tags: bash

I have written some little code but it seems not to work as I want to.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
        xdg-open test.mp4
        inotifywait -e modify test.mp4

done
```

Simply I want to open a .mp4 file but it can be replaced anytime and if it replaced one day the script should be recognize it and restart the .mp4 file again.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Use `inotifywait` instead of `inotifywatch`:

```
while true; do
    inotifywait -e modify file.mp4
    xdg-open file.mp4
done 2>&1 > /dev/null & disown ; exit
```

Basically it `xdg-open file.mp4`, sleeps until modify, reopens it...

Comment: @Deezer I made this script disown and exit after launch. It starts every time a file is edited

Comment: How can I do it that it starts everytime again when its over?

Comment: @Deezer use `while true` loop

Comment: now it starts everytime so it doesn´t wait until the movie is over

Comment: @Deezer probably the file test.mp4 is missing, so it does not wait.

Comment: No it´s there. Now I edit my code look at it. the problem is. it starts one time until it ends but how can I do it as a loop and if it changed it starts with the new file